# NoMethodError in ParticipantsController#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Why does the error occur?

There hasen't been an adquate/similar solution for my problem. I just could find some tips and tricks here but now I am stuck.

We have a course management system. You can add new coures, participants and persons among other things. I had to change the database. Now there is a **persons** table, too. Earlier all informations about persons respectively participants where just saved in the **participants** table. Now when a **new participant** is added the **persons** table is involved. 
We want to add a new participant of a course. I adjusted the **new action** in the participants controller and I was hoping passing all data like in the old way. The old way was working to add a new participant.

Earlier the way was: course **>** new participant form

Now it is: course **>** search for a person to use it in the form **>** new participant form

I think (better ways accepted) I just adjust the old code?! Below is my try.

The Error

> **NoMethodError in ParticipantsController#new** undefined method `participants' for []:Array

occurs.

**Here are the old classes:**

**Model Course**

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participants
```

**Model Participant**

```
class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :function
```

**ParticipantsController**

```
class ParticipantsController < ApplicationController

....
 def new
    @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
    @participant = @course.participants.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @participant }
    end
  end

 def create
    @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
    @participant = @course.participants.new(params[:participant])
    @course.updated_by = current_user.cn
    @course.send(:create_version)
    @course.tag_version(t(:participant_added))
    @course.save!

    respond_to do |format|
      if @participant.save
        format.html { redirect_to course_path(@participant.course), notice: 'Participant was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @participant, status: :created, location: @participant }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @participant.errors, status:     :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

When you look below at the course view snippet there is the old and new path to the form. Note that the person search is in between the course and the new participant form now.

```
**old**    <%= link_to t(:add), new_course_participant_path(@course) %>

**new**    <%= link_to t(:add), course_persons_path(@course, @person)%>
```

**Here are the new classes**

```
class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :function
  belongs_to :person

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participants
  has_many :courses, through:  :participants
```

Here are my adjustments in the ParticipantsController. My thoughts are maybe naive because I am still learning ruby on rails.

```
class ParticipantsController < ApplicationController
    def new
       @person = Person.find(params[:person_id])
       @participant = Participant.find_by_person_id(params[:person_id])
       @course= Course.find(:all, :conditions => {:id => @participant})
       @participant = @course.participants.build

   respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @participant }
    end
  end


 def create 
    @course= Course.find(params[:course_id])
    @participant = @course.participants.new(params[:participant])
    @course.updated_by = current_user.cn
    @course.send(:create_version)
    @course.tag_version(t(:participant_added))
    @course.save!

    respond_to do |format|
      if @participant.save
        format.html { redirect_to course_path(@participant.course), notice:     'Participant was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @participant, status: :created, location: @participant }

      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @participant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: your `@course` as result of `Course.find(:all, :conditions => {:id => @participant})` is an empty array, there's no way to access to `participants` from it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But why did id work in the old code?

Comment: What Rails version are you using?

Comment: In the Gemfile is `gem rails, 3.2.13`

Comment: I don't see any `@course = Course.find(:all, :conditions => {:id => @participant})` in your old code. There was `@course = Course.find(params[:course_id])`

Comment: @AntonTkachov Yes, you are right. But in my thinking it got all information like in the old colde. I am just assuming. Due to the error it does not. Where is my mistake?

Comment: @MarcelB `Course.find(:all, ....)` returns an array with all matches. `Course.find(params[:course_id])` returns a first record, that have matched id. Why do you expect course id to be equal any data from participant?

Comment: @AntonTkachov Hm, ok. It cannot handle the `:all` because in the old colde it just returned one and now it returns all, right? How can I correct the `@course = Course.find(:all, :conditions => {:id => @participant})`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite:

```
@person = Person.find(params[:person_id])
@participant = Participant.find_by_person_id(params[:person_id])
@course= Course.find(:all, :conditions => {:id => @participant})
@participant = @course.participants.build
```

To:

```
@person = Person.find(params[:person_id])
@course = Participant.find_by_person_id(params[:person_id]).course
@participant = @course.participants.build
```

Watch for out for exception in case `Participant.find_by_person_id(params[:person_id])` returns a nil

Comment: @MarcelB BTW, do you really need this `@person` object? Do you use it somewhere? I think no need to load it

Comment: I use the person in the form. Like an autofill function. If an authorized user wants to add a new participant the user can search for already existing persons. If a person is already existing as a participant in the system in the form I load the searched person. The fields in the form are `readonly: true`. Like this `<%= f.text_field :prename, value:  @person.prename, readonly: true, style: 'background-color:#BDBDBD', size: 35  %>`

Comment: @AntonTkachow When I click the submit button now there is this error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ParticipantsController#create Couldn't find Course without an ID. And when I put in the create action `@course = Participant.find_by_person_id(params[:person_id]).course` this error appears: NoMethodError in ParticipantsController#create undefined method course for nil:NilClass

Comment: @MarcelB 'Couldn't find Course without an ID' => Then you don't send `course_id` parameter to `create`. 'undefined method course for nil:NilClass' I've wrote you -- 'Watch for out for exception in case Participant.find_by_person_id(params[:person_id]) returns a nil'. It means that you have no participant records for this exact person and you need to handle a case if your participant is blank. I would just pass there a separate 'course_id' parameter and rewrite course load logic to `@course = Course.find(params[:course_id])`

Comment: @AntonTkachow But in fact there are participant records. I tryed to search several persons and went to the `new participant` form. I checked the database. E.g. there are 48 records for that participant. I am confused. How can I get the `course_id` in the create action? Doesn't this line `@course = Participant.find_by_person_id(params[:person_id]).course` look for the participant by the `person_id` and "get" by that the course? Hm is it possible to add to this line something like `.course.id?`

Comment: @AntonTkachow The old way you see was without the `person search` between. In the old way there was the path `new_course_participant_path(@course)`. But from the `person search` I don't know if it is possible to get the `@course` and pass it further to the `new participant form`.

Comment: Perhaps I should mention that in the database only a new `participant` record shold be created. But no new person record.

Comment: @MarcelB Check your parameters for exact person_id, that you get and then check in console, that you really have participants for this person. Also, if participant is a connection table between course and person, they your logic is not valid at all, because you need participant for exact person and course, not only person. PS: This goes far away from initial questions and turns into 'let me code it for you' :) You need to go deeper into it on your own

Comment: @AntonTkachow Thank you for your help. I've never worked with the console on this system. They use putty and vim here... in tutorials its way more fancy. But now I have access to the console and it is really helpful. Btw creating a participant now works but it doesn't catches the person_id. But I am working on it.